# SignalR with multilple Jquery Ajax calls on same page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, model-view-controller, signalr

I had embedded SignalR in my mvc app for real time notifications.
Everything works fine, then there comes this problem that I inserted the code below in the layout page, The child pages also have some ajax calls which populate kendogrid on respective pages. When using signalR those ajax calls do not run. Please help me solving this problem.. Following is the code

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/signalR/hubs"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {

            // Proxy created on the fly
            var job = $.connection.signalRHub;

            // Declare a function on the job hub so the server can invoke it
            job.client.displayStatus = function () {
                getData();
            };

            // Start the connection
            $.connection.hub.start();
            getData();
        });
        $.noConflict();
        function getData() {
            var $tbl = $('#lastNotify');

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/TeacherConsole/GetData",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function (data) {
                    //data = JSON.parse(data.d);
                    console.log(data);
                    // if (Object.keys(data).length > 0) {
                    var newdata = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data || null));

                    var rows = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < newdata.length; i++) {
                        console.log(newdata[i].Body);
                        $tbl.empty();
                        $('#lastNotify').append(newdata[i].Title);
                    }
                    $tbl.append(rows.join(''));
                    //}
                },
                error: function (request, status, error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    console.log(request.responseText);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>



 public ActionResult GetData()
        {
            var view = new IndexTeacherConsoleView();
            this.FillBaseView(view);
            string userID = view.BaseUserId;

            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DataBase"].ConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT Top 1 [Title],[Body] FROM [SMSDB_NEW].[dbo].[UserNotifications] where to_id='" + userID + "' and isRead=0 order by CreationDate desc", connection))
                {
                    command.Notification = null;
                    SqlDependency.Start(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DataBase"].ConnectionString);
                    SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                    dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

                    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                        connection.Open();

                    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        var read = reader.Cast<IDataRecord>()
                            .Select(x => new NotificationProperties()
                            {
                                Title = x.GetString(0),
                                Body = x.GetString(1),
                            }).ToList();
                        return Json(read);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
        {
            SignalRHub.Show();
        }
```